# Why am I getting a "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string" when attempting to create a clone of the Vuex store in a Jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a working Vue 2.6 / Vuex 3.6 / TypeScript application. I wanted to add some unit tests to it before doing some complex refactoring. Once I had Jest and Vue Test Utils all installed and configured I tried to follow the instructions available in the [official Vue Test Utils guide](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-a-running-store).

Adapting the instructions to my specific project looked something like this:

```js
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vue'
import store from 'store'
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

test("SET_CURRENT_VTK_INDEX_SLICES should update the VTK index slices", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(Vuex)
  const store = new Vuex.Store(cloneDeep(storeConfig))
  expect(store.state.iIndexSlice).toBe(0)
  store.commit('SET_CURRENT_VTK_INDEX_SLICES', { indexAxis: 'i', value: 1 })
})
```

But when I executed `npm run test:unit` I received the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string"

I didn't think there were any symbols in the store but used a recursive function to check the store and all it's children. (I filched this code from somewhere I can't recall):

```js
function findSymbolInStore(store) {
      for (const key in store) {
        console.log(key);
        if (store.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const value = store[key];
          if (typeof value === 'object') {
            if (value instanceof Symbol) {
              console.log(`Symbol found: ${key}`);
            } else {
              findSymbolInStore(value);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

 findSymbolInStore(store.state);
```

This didn't find any symbols in the store.

I went down a few other dead ends, tried stringifying the store to see where the symbol was:

```js
try {
 const thisStore = JSON.stringify(store);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error converting object to string;', err);
}
```

But this threw an error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Then tried stringifying with `flatted`:

```js
import flatted from 'flatted';

const stringifyStore = flatted.stringify(store);
const parsedStore = flatted.parse(stringifyStore);
```

This seemed to advance me a little further, now I was getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iIndexSlice')

Which was weird because I could see that `iIndexStore` had a default value of 0 in the store. Thankfully, at this point [Amit Patel](https://redblobgames.com/) put me on the right track by pointing out that not only was `iIndexSlice` undefined, the entire `store.state` was undefined.

I stumbled upon a [Vuex GitHub issue][4] that had a similar error to one I was facing:

> [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.currentView" is {}

In the above referenced issue the author suggests not exporting the store but only the store's configuration. I realized that the app's store was exporting an actual store instance. The Vuex store definition looked something like:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
  iIndexSlice: 0,
  // ...
 },
 getters: {
  currentView(state) {
   // Function code ...
  }
 mutations: {
  // code
 },
 actions: {
  // code
 }
});

export default store;
```

But now what?

HT: To [Mujeeb](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mujeebansari786/) who helped me with some of the symbol debugging.

Note: I could have skipped over the dead ends, etc. but I figured someone else might hit the same hard stops and that Googling for an answer might be easier if some of the errors, etc. are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

(Welcome to another episode of "Dave spent way too much time figuring this out...it's pretty trivial but hoping to save that 1 other person who will make the same mistakes):

I refactored the Vuex store to look like this:

```js
export const storeConfig = {
 state: {
  iIndexSlice: 0,
  // ...
 },
 getters: {
  currentView(state) {
   // Function code ...
  }
 mutations: {
  // code
 },
 actions: {
  // code
 }
};

const store = new Vuex.Store(storeConfig);

export default store;
```

Then I just needed one tiny tweak to my Jest test:

```js
// import store from './store'
// to:
import { storeConfig } from './store'
})
```

And now the test runs without issue.